# What is a Plain Text Translation of this SQL Query?

Tags: python, sql, mysql, query-optimization

My SQL knowledge is really basic, and need some help in *translating* this rather long query (running in a python script querying some AWS athena database, with some f-strings embedded) to plain English or flow chart. I understand concepts of SELECT * WHERE, JOINS etc., but this seems really advanced, renaming multiple tables and handling multiple cases.

```
SELECT usc_customer_id, escape_customer_id, use_sms, 
start_date, least(date('{segment_date_str}'), max(booking_date)) as 
"max_booking_date", 
date('{segment_date_str}') as segment_date,
count(t.job_no) as bookings, count(a.trip_no) as trips, 
sum(total_trip_fare) as total_fare, sum(promo_amt) as "promo_amount", 
sum(case when promo_amt > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as promo_times
FROM   
(
    SELECT m.usc_customer_id, m.escape_customer_id, use_sms, 
    case when date(user_create_time) > date('{start_date}') then date(
    user_create_time)
        else date('{start_date}') end as start_date,  
    date(b."req_pickup_dt") as booking_date,
        j.job_no, j.status
      FROM  (SELECT m.*, 
              CASE WHEN news_sms = 1 OR third_party_sms = 1 THEN True
              ELSE False END AS use_sms,
                greatest(COALESCE(c.create_time, 
                m.usc_customer_create_time,m.escape_customer_create_time),
                    COALESCE(m.usc_customer_create_time, 
                    m.escape_customer_create_time, c.create_time), 
                    COALESCE(m.escape_customer_create_time, c.create_time, 
                    m.usc_customer_create_time)) as user_create_time
                FROM "publish_cab"."usc_customer" c join 
                customer_mapping m 
                on c.customer_id = m.usc_customer_id where country_code = 
                '65') m
           join "publish_cab"."escape_booking" as b
                on m.escape_customer_id = b.cust_id
           join "publish_cab"."escape_job" as j
                on b.booking_id = j.booking_id
      where b.bookingdate between '{start_date_short}' and '
{segment_date_str_short}'
        and j.createddate between '{start_date_short}' and '
{segment_date_str_short}'
) t   
left join (
    select * from "publish_cab"."escape_trip_details" 
    where createddate between '{start_date_short}' and '
{segment_date_str_short}'
) a
on  t.job_no = a.job_no
group by usc_customer_id, escape_customer_id, start_date, use_sms
```

Would be grateful if it can be translated into some sort of block diagrammatic flow chart, or corresponding pandas dataframe operations for someone who is relatively new to SQL, but in general understands programming and data structures well.

Answer (score 1):

You ask "how may I understand the *meaning* of SELECT ... ?"

Just review the rows.
(You have the data, we don't.)
It's an onion.
Start on the inside, and work your way out.

That `SELECT m.*, ...` creates a new relation,
a new table based upon `usc_customer`.
As such, it can be JOINed against `escape_booking`
and `escape_job`, which in turn produces *another* relation.

As stated these relations have a bunch of complex syntax
and can look kind of big and scary.
So tame that complexity.
Use `CREATE VIEW usc_customer_report_v AS SELECT ...`
to encapsulate all those expressions into a named relationship
that you can conveniently query and JOIN against.

That 3-way JOIN could go into an `escape_v` view
for the same reasons.
And finally the `SELECT m.usc_customer_id, ...`
might go into yet another view.

At that point you're looking at a *much* simpler
overall query.
And you can reason about each of the ingredients
independently, reviewing and debugging them
if you feel they don't capture quite the proper rows
for your business problem.

---

Life is full of complex relationships.
Often the act of descriptively *naming*
those relationships is the first step
to abstracting what they *mean*,
and viewing them from a higher perspective.

Think about a library.
It contains alphabetic letters,
a great many letters, when viewed up close.
Take a step back and we see words, sentences,
paragraphs, chapters, books,
each with their own themes.
Armed with the Dewey Decimal system
we might step further back
and survey a bookshelf devoted
to chemistry, another to physics.
Use the power of abstraction to
zoom out to the big picture,
then zoom in to what you currently find
are the details of interest.
Putting names on things
helps us to make abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your data model and meaning of these fields it's pretty tough to describe it in a way that would be more clear than sql. SQL is actually remarkably well designed for dictating transformations.

... but, rewriting to use CTEs (Common table expressions, "with" clause section you see below) it might be easier to see how the names correspond to each piece.

```
with 
/*

Define chunks of the query.

<name> as (<query body>) 

You can think of that as assigning the result of the query body to a named variable.

Note the indentation, each named block starts at the beginning of the line. Don't get confused by the column aliases ex case when yada then yada end AS something. That just assigns the result of that case statement to column name.

See main body lower


*/
customer_mapping_for_country_65_and_dates as (
    SELECT m.*, 
           CASE WHEN news_sms = 1 
                  OR third_party_sms = 1 THEN True
                ELSE False 
           END AS use_sms,
           greatest(
            COALESCE(
             c.create_time, 
             m.usc_customer_create_time,
             m.escape_customer_create_time
             ),
            COALESCE(
             m.usc_customer_create_time, 
             m.escape_customer_create_time, c.create_time), 
             COALESCE(m.escape_customer_create_time, c.create_time, 
             m.usc_customer_create_time)
            ) as user_create_time
      FROM "publish_cab"."usc_customer" c 
      join customer_mapping m 
        on c.customer_id = m.usc_customer_id 
     where country_code = '65'),
customer_jobs_constrained_by_parameter_dates as (
    SELECT cmcd.usc_customer_id, 
           cmcd.escape_customer_id, use_sms, 
           case when date(user_create_time) > date('{start_date}') then
                     date(user_create_time)
                else date('{start_date}') 
            end as start_date,  
           date(b."req_pickup_dt") as booking_date,
           j.job_no, 
           j.status
      FROM customer_mapping_for_country_65_and_dates cmcd
      join "publish_cab"."escape_booking" as b
        on cmcd.escape_customer_id = b.cust_id
      join "publish_cab"."escape_job" as j
        on b.booking_id = j.booking_id
     where b.bookingdate 
           between '{start_date_short}' and '{segment_date_str_short}'
       and j.createddate 
           between '{start_date_short}' and '{segment_date_str_short}')
,
escape_trips_between_constraint_dates as (
    select *   
      from "publish_cab"."escape_trip_details" 
     where createddate 
           between '{start_date_short}' and '{segment_date_str_short}')
/*

Main body.

Use all of your defined chunks together.

*/
SELECT usc_customer_id, 
       escape_customer_id, 
       use_sms, 
       start_date, 
       least(
           date('{segment_date_str}'), max(booking_date)) as "max_booking_date", 
       date('{segment_date_str}') as segment_date,
       count(t.job_no) as bookings, count(a.trip_no) as trips, 
       sum(total_trip_fare) as total_fare, sum(promo_amt) as "promo_amount", 
       sum(case when promo_amt > 0 then 1 
                else 0 
           end) as promo_times
  from customer_jobs_constrained_by_parameter_dates t 
  left
  join escape_trips_between_constraint_dates a 
    on t.job_no = a.job_no
 group 
    by usc_customer_id, 
       escape_customer_id, 
       start_date, 
       use_sms
```